# database exception base table or view not found

Tags: laravel-5

ı download any a laravel project and after command artisan migrate 'database exception base table or view not found' ı saw this. What should ı make. please help

Answer (score 0):

You did't created the table or view. First you have to run the following command to create the table.

```
php artisan make:migration create_table_name --create=table_name
```

open the newly created migration file for updating the fields name of the table.
Now you can run the following command.

```
   php artisan migrate
```

Comment: public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('ayarlar', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('value');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

Comment: when ı run php artisan migrate  ı get the this error ' Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'blog.ayarlar' doesn't exist (SQL: select `value`, `name`  [39;49m'

Comment: php artisan migrate command works when you have newly created migrations. if you don't have any migration . then there is nothing to migrate.

Comment: because ı download this project from github and for database ı have to make migration . I downloaded another project its works but in this project ı always get this error.

Comment: and when ı run composer install command ı got this error 'Script php artisan optimize handling the post-install-cmd event returned with error code 1'  ı think my problem about this.